# Stubbed method not called when using mockito Spy on Class method

Tags: java, mockito

Source code:

```
GetOptionBidPrice getOptionBidPrice = new GetOptionBidPrice(. . .);
double bidPrice = getOptionBidPrice.getBidPrice();
```

Test code:

```
GetOptionBidPrice spyGetOptionBidPrice = spy(GetOptionBidPrice.class);
doReturn(100.0).when(spyGetOptionBidPrice).getBidPrice();

.... Tests the source code....
```

The mocked and returned value of 100.0 is not received by the source code, instead if receives 0 which is the field default in the real class GetOptionBidPrice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 0):

Spies and mocks are meant to be used as dependencies to other methods. What your production code is doing is creating its own instance of `GetOptionBidPrice` instead of using the spy you've just created in your test.

To fix that, use dependency injection. Instead of

```
    GetOptionBidPrice getOptionBidPrice = new GetOptionBidPrice(. . .);
    double bidPrice = getOptionBidPrice.getBidPrice();
```

You should pass `getOptionBidPrice` as an argument to your method:

```
public void myMethod(GetOptionBidPrice getOptionBidPrice) {
    double bidPrice = getOptionBidPrice.getBidPrice();
```

And then the caller of your method in production code passes a real instance created with `new GetOptionBidPrice(. . .)` while your test code passes it a spy.